# How do I change profile name on Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have two children with two accounts for Minecraft. When we log in and play we are taken to the other users world. How can we separate both accounts on the PC? Please help, mother very confused!

Comment: Are they logging in with the same Windows account?  Also, there are ways to change which folder saves are loaded from, as well as a way to change the user that's logged in.

Comment: I'm confused, you make worlds in minecraft, why not just login to a different world?

Comment: I am somewhat confused by what you are even asking. -1 for lack of detail.

Answer (score 3):

If you're on Windows, you could have a batch file to run for each child.

Here's an example (for John):

```
@echo off
set APPDATA=%~dp0\John
set LAUNCHER=Minecraft.exe
%LAUNCHER%
```

This script will change the `%APPDATA%` variable to wherever your batch script is with the "John" directory within. This will create two separate instances of Minecraft all together, so not only worlds (saves) are separate, but the whole game (resource packs, Java binaries, etc).
You would naturally change "John" to whatever your child's name is.

Hope this helped.

Comment: `%CD%` is a bit confusing. I suggest `%~dp0`

Comment: I've never used `%~dp0` before, but if it does the same thing as `%CD%`, then I suppose it's more down to preference?

Comment: It uses the directory the script is located in as the working directory. With `%CD%`, it uses the current directory, which under certain circumstances, could be bad if the command prompt was used and then used to launch the script.

Comment: To be honest, if it isn't the asker launching the script, it won't be invoked from command line (the children by the sounds of it are less than 10 years old). I'll still change it though

Comment: This is a nice answer, but it may be too complicated for some users.

Answer (score 2):

You can make two separate profiles on the new launcher, clcik the `New Profile` button.

[image]

This screen will appear.

[image]

If you don't know what to do on this screen, leave everything the way it is except for the name

You can edit either profile at any time by clicking the `Edit Profile` button.